# MySQL database is getting escaped wrong; cannot import it on Windows

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, drupal-7

I have a giant MySQL database (about 1.2GB, Drupal installation) that I am working with on the Mac.  On the Mac, I can import it and export it between various dev servers with no trouble.

Now, I am trying to import the database into MySQL on Windows 10.  When I do so, I'm getting the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Patrick\Sites\devdesktop\omsearch>drush @loc.om sql-cli < ../output.sql
ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1253: Unknown MySQL server host 'want' (0)

C:\Users\Patrick\Sites\devdesktop\omsearch>drush @loc.om sql-cli < ../20160415dd.sql
ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 3023: Unknown MySQL server host 'animal' (0)
```

These words "want" and "animal" are text in a user's profile, not MySQL server hosts. So, somehow, the SQL file is not being escaped properly for import on Windows.

I am not terribly well-versed in MySQL, but I know the following from the Drupal database configuration:

- charset: utf8mb4
- collation: utf8mb4_general_ci

**What I tried**

I used Drush, the drupal command line tool, to export the database.  This calls `mysqldrump` and I used the default options.

I then tried `mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 DATABASE -r DATABASE.sql`.  This also gives the same error.

**Example of the problem line**

```
ifficultâ¦.Im try.I can speak Japanese.\r\n\r\nThe favorite thing is a movie and an animalâ¡','','plain_text'),('node','self_introduction',0,42898,64071,'und',0,'I would love to know people, specially
```

(This may not be showing up properly because it seems VIM is also having trouble displaying the characters.)

Comment: Show some sample data around those words

Comment: What are you expecting instead of `â¦`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the export but with the importing command.

To import on Windows, I had to do this:

`mysql DATABASE --default-character-set=utf8mb4 < DATABASE.sql`

The important thing to add is the explication character set declaration: `--default-character-set=utf8mb4`.